# Problem in feeding data in multi-output image classification model in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Facing problem in creating multi-output classification model in keras.

Data : images are in a folder.
Labels are in separate numpy arrays (i.e. black.npy and blue.npy).

Platform : kaggle

Images are preprocessed and splitted into train, val and test numpy arrays
i.e train_img_array, val_img_array, test_img_array

Label arrays are also splitted and converted into one-hot encoded format
ie. train_black_c, train_blue_c,
val_black_c, val_blue_c, test_black_c, test_blue_c

model is created like this :

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.layers import GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

vgg = VGG16(input_shape = (224, 224, 3), weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

for layer in vgg.layers:
layer.trainable = False

x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(vgg.output)
x = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)

black_out = Dense(2, activation = 'softmax', name = 'black')(x)
blue_out = Dense(2, activation = 'softmax', name = 'blue')(x)

output = [black_out, blue_out]

model = Model(inputs = vgg.input, outputs = output)

model.summary()
```

compiled model like this :

```
model.compile(loss={'black' : 'categorical_crossentropy', 
                'blue' : 'categorical_crossentropy'}, 
         optimizer = {'black' : 'adam', 
                      'blue' : 'adam'},
         metrics = {'black' : 'accuracy', 
                    'blue' : 'accuracy'} )
```

But, while calling fit method facing error:

```
history = model.fit(x = train_img_array,
                y = {'black' : train_black_c,
                    'blue' : train_blue_c},
               batch_size = 32,
               epochs = 100,
               validation_data = (val_img_array, 
                                  {'black' : val_black_c,
                                  'blue' : val_blue_c}) )
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-3caee4dc67c9> in <module>
      67                    validation_data = (val_img_array, 
      68                                       {'black' : val_black_c,
 ---> 69                                       'blue' : val_blue_c}) )
      70 
      71 print("Training completed.")

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in 
fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, 
shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, 
validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
     1098                 _r=1):
     1099               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
  -> 1100               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
     1101               if data_handler.should_sync:
     1102                 context.async_wait()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in 
__call__(self, *args, **kwds)
     826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
     827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
 --> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
     829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
     830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in 
_call(self, *args, **kwds)
     869       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
     870       initializers = []
 --> 871       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
     872     finally:
     873       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in 
_initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
     724     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
     725         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # 
pylint: disable=protected-access
 --> 726             *args, **kwds))
     727 
     728     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in 
_get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
     2967       args, kwargs = None, None
     2968     with self._lock:
  -> 2969       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
     2970     return graph_function
     2971 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in 
_maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
     3359 
     3360           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
  -> 3361           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
     3362           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
     3363 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in 
_create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
     3204             arg_names=arg_names,
     3205             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
  -> 3206             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
     3207         self._function_attributes,
     3208         function_spec=self.function_spec,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in 
func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, 
autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, 
capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
     988         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
     989 
 --> 990       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
     991 
     992       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in 
wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
     632             xla_context.Exit()
     633         else:
 --> 634           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
     635         return out
     636 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in 
wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     975           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
     976             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
 --> 977               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
     978             else:
     979               raise

AttributeError: in user code:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:805 train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:795 step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1259 run
    return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
    return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:788 run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:757 train_step
    self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'minimize'
```

Comment: Can you share `train_img_array` to replicate your issue? so that we can try to help you. Thanks!

Comment: yeah, sure. This is the link to datset that i m using. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Sl49lrZ8EhFgUE4gq8MhX0vY_JFHMCO8/view?usp=sharing